# Converting a string to a DateTime in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I am writing an application to take SNMP data from an APC UPS and I want to do something with that data.

A few of the bits of information that I'm getting come in this format:

> 0d 2h 5m 45s 0ms

I want to be able to do something if that value goes under 30 minutes (total time - including the days and hours).

If I can get that string to be converted into a DateTime, then I can perform calculations on it.

I guess I'm looking to add that string to Now()... that way I can query how far in the future it is.

I hope that makes sense?

In my head the code looks something like this:

```
Dim timeNow As DateTime = Now
Dim snmpRuntimeRemaining As DateTime = Now + snmpDataTime
Dim runtimeRemaining As TimeSpan = snmpRuntimeRemaining - timeNow
If runtimeRemaining.TotalMinutes >= 30 Then Do Something
```

Comment: I think you should look at the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) structure not to a DateTime

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Your milliseconds is always zero or did you get values with two or three digits also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went a slightly different route away from Regex, and it needs tidying up - but this here is how I did it:

```
Dim snmpTimeDate As String = "0d 2h 5m 45s 0ms"
Dim split() As String = snmpTimeDate.Split(" ")
Dim days As String = split(0).Replace("d", "")
Dim hours As String = split(1).Replace("h", "")
Dim minutes As String = split(2).Replace("m", "")
Dim seconds As String = split(3).Replace("s", "")
Dim miliseconds As String = split(4).Replace("ms", "")
Dim snmpToTimeSpan = New TimeSpan(days, hours, minutes, seconds, miliseconds)
Dim snmpDateTime = DateTime.Now + snmpToTimeSpan
Dim runtimeRemaining As TimeSpan = snmpDateTime - DateTime.Now
If runtimeRemaining.TotalMinutes >= 30 Then Do Something
```

Thanks to Gerino for his help!

Answer (score 2):

To add to .Now():

```
var t = new TimeSpan(days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
var d = DateTime.Now + t;
```

Days, hours etc. you can get using a named Regex groups:

```
var r = new Regex(@"(?<days>\d+)d (?<hours>\d+)h...");
var m = r.Match(input);
var days = m.Groups["days"].Value;
```

PS You don't need to actually add to .Now, you can just do:

```
var t1 = (as above)
var t2 = Timespan.FromMinutes(30);
if(t1 < t2) doSth(); // if timespan from string is less (shorter) than 30 minutes
```

Code is in C#, but I think you can adapt it easily :)